# Como saber qual a semana de um determinado mês?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou trabalhando em ASP.NET MVC 4, e pretendo saber qual é a semana de um determinado mês.

Por exemplo, o utilizador pretende definir uma frequência de ocorrências, e como tal diz:

- A ocorrência vai acontecer a cada `2` semanas;
- A ocorrência vai acontecer nessa semana à segunda-feira e quinta-feira;

Ao obter estes dados do utilizador, tenho de gerar uma lista de datas com estes dados. O resultado da lista será algo como:

`03/02/2014` - corresponde à segunda-feira da segunda semana de Fevereiro;

`06/02/2014` - corresponde à quinta-feira da segunda semana de Fevereiro;

`17/02/2014` - corresponde à segunda-feira da quarta semana de Fevereiro;

`20/02/2014` - corresponde à quinta-feira da quarta semana de Fevereiro;

`03/03/2014` - corresponde à segunda-feira da primeira semana de Março;

`06/03/2014` - corresponde à quinta-feira da primeira semana de Março;

... Por ai fora

Como tal quero tentar saber como calcular/saber as semanas do mês (penso que a solução passa por saber o número da semana no ano), e ainda o dia da semana nessa mesma semana.

Comment: Sua semana começa em qual dia? Domingo? Segunda?

Comment: Começa numa Segunda-feira

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escrevi este algoritmo

1. Calcula o primeiro dia da semana actual (no meu exemplo, o primeiro dia da semana e' o Domingo).
2. Calcula a segunda-feira e a quinta-feira desta semana, e adiciona a' lista
3. Avanca 2 semanas, e volta ao passo 2

Dados de input

- `weekCount`: numero total de semanas a examinar
- `skipWeeks`: numero de semanas para saltar/avancar. No teu exemplo em que "A ocorrência vai acontecer a cada 2 semanas", skipWeeks seria 1. Ou seja, o algoritmo vai examinar uma semana, avancar 1 semana, examinar a semana, avancar 1 semana, etc.
- `daysOfWeek`: dias da semana (ex: `new[] {DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday}`)
- (opcional) `startDate`: dia para comecar a pesquisa. Por defeito e' o dia actual.

---

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> AgendarAlertas(int weekCount, int skipWeeks, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek )
{
    return AgendarAlertas(weekCount, skipWeeks, daysOfWeek, DateTime.Today);
}

public IEnumerable<DateTime> AgendarAlertas(int weekCount, int skipWeeks, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek , DateTime startDate)
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    DateTime firstDayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);

    for (int currentWeek = 0; currentWeek < weekCount; currentWeek++)
    {
        //calcular dias da semana
        dates.AddRange(
            daysOfWeek.Select(dayOfWeek =>
                                firstDayOfWeek.NextDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek)));

        //avancar "skipWeeks"
        firstDayOfWeek = calendar.AddWeeks(firstDayOfWeek, skipWeeks + 1);
        currentWeek += skipWeeks;
    }

    //filtrar dias passados
    return dates.SkipWhile(date => date < startDate);
}
```

Sao precisos 2 *extension methods*

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime NextDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek day)
    {
        int diff = day - dt.DayOfWeek;

        //se o dia ja passou, calcular o da proxima semana
        if (diff < 0)
            diff += 7;

        return dt.AddDays(diff).Date;
    }

    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
            diff += 7;

        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

Resultado :

```
AgendarAlertas(11, 1, new[] {DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday});

06/02/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira
07/02/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira
20/02/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira + 2 semanas
21/02/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira  + 2 semanas
06/03/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira + 4 semanas
07/03/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira  + 4 semanas
20/03/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira + 6 semanas
21/03/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira  + 6 semanas
03/04/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira + 8 semanas
04/04/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira  + 8 semanas
17/04/2014 00:00:00 //proxima quinta-feira + 10 semanas
18/04/2014 00:00:00 //proxima sexta-feira  + 10 semanas
```

Comment: Testei ambas as respostas e funcionam correctamente. Embora a outra seja mais "fácil" de implementar a sua também está bastante completa! Obrigado ;)

Comment: @CesarMiguel So para lembrar que a outra forma tem pior performance.. Se quiseres as segundas feiras do próximo ano, com um intervalo de 2 semanas , o loop vai correr ~365 vezes. O meu loop correria 52 / 2 = 26 vezes, uma por cada semana do ano, saltando as semanas que não interessam.

Comment: @CesarMiguel melhorei o algoritmo para ser mais facil de usar e de ler, e melhorei tambem a performance um pouco.

Comment: Obrigado @dcastro , deste grande ajuda! Vou proceder às alterações.

Answer (score 3):

## **Opção 1:**

```
public static void obterDiasComIntervaloSemanal(DateTime data, int intervalo, int total_semanas, DayOfWeek[] dias)
{
    int semana_atual = 1;    
    while (semana_atual <= total_semanas)
    {
        if (dias.Contains(data.DayOfWeek) && semana_atual % intervalo == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); // Aqui você decide o quer fazer se quiser adicionar numa lista de datas a data atual...
        if (data.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            semana_atual++;
        data = data.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

E para utilizar:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DayOfWeek[] dias = {
                       DayOfWeek.Monday,
                       DayOfWeek.Thursday
                   };
    obterDiasComIntervaloSemanal(new DateTime(2014, 02, 01), 2, 10, dias);
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## **Opção 2:**

```
public static DateTime getDateInterval(int year, int month, int week, DayOfWeek day)
{
    int current_week = 1;
    var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == day && current_week == week)
            break;
        if (date.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            current_week++;
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return date;
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
                           // year month week   day of week
    var data1 = getDateInterval(2014, 2, 2, DayOfWeek.Monday); // 03/02/2014
    var data2 = getDateInterval(2014, 2, 2, DayOfWeek.Thursday); // 06/02/2014
    var data3 = getDateInterval(2014, 2, 4, DayOfWeek.Monday); // 17/02/2014
}
```

Comment: O algoritmo tem bug. Se eu quiser os Domingos, vai entrar em loop infinito e acabar em stack overflow. Acho que basta tirar o `else` para resolver o bug.

Comment: Realmente dcastro, obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvendo seu problema da forma mais símples: um for iterando diretamente sobre datas.

Fica assim:

```
var date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 4);
var intervaloSemanas = 2;
var diasDaSemana = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, };

var dataDeStop = date.AddDays(80);
var incremento = TimeSpan.FromDays(7 * intervaloSemanas);

for (var dt = date.AddDays(-(int)date.DayOfWeek);
     dt <= dataDeStop;
     dt += incremento)
{
    foreach (var dayOfWeek in diasDaSemana)
        Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy'-'MM'-'dd}", dt.AddDays((int)dayOfWeek));
}
```

Output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse código também é bem rápido, pois vai direto nas datas que você quer.