# Como saber o número de uma semana em cada mês

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou trabalhando em ASP MVC4, e gostava saber qual o número das semanas num determinado mês para gerar uma lista com datas. Por exemplo, o utilizador insere uma semana, e nessa semana de cada mês vou gerar uma data.
O utilizador pode inserir a semana do mês em que a ocorrência vai acontecer (na qual vou gerar a data):

`primeira` - Primeira semana do mês

`segunda` - Segunda semana do mês

`terceira` - Terceira semana do mês

`quarta` - Quarta semana do mês

`ultima` - Última semana do mês

No fim de o utilizador escolher a semana do mês, vou gerar uma data para essa mesma semana no mês, à Segunda-feira.
Supondo que o utilizador insere `terceira`
Vou gerar uma lista com as datas:

`10/02/2014` - data na terceira semana do mês de Fevereiro, à Segunda-feira

`10/03/2014` - data na terceira semana do mês de Março, à Segunda-feira

`14/04/2014` - data na terceira semana do mês de Abril, à Segunda-feira

Comment: Estou a pensar criar uma lista de datas para cada semana no mês. Vejo onde o dia 1 do mês se encontra (na semana) e começo a gerar as listas (uma lista para cada semana), a partir dessa data. Será a maneira mais correcta?

Comment: Já tem uma questão muito similar [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4091/como-saber-qual-a-semana-de-um-determinado-mes) vê se não te serve?

Comment: Essa questão até fui que a coloquei. Acaba por ser questões diferentes, porque aqui quero de 1 a 5 o número da semana no mês, onde começa e onde acaba cada. A outra questão não tem forma de saber qual a segunda ou terceira semana de um determinado mês

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 5):

O blog Elsdesire possui esta pergunta seguinda da [resposta](http://elsdesire.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/c-get-week-number-in-month.html) ( em inglês ).

A implementação apresentada é esta:

```
public static int GetWeekInMonth(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime tempdate = date.AddDays(-date.Day + 1);
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    int weekNumStart = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(tempdate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, ciCurr.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, ciCurr.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    return weekNum - weekNumStart + 1;
}
```

Apesar de não ter testado o código, descorrendo ele é possível prever que ele faz o que você necessita.

Comment: Estive a experimentar a sua solução, e a verdade é que consigo saber a semana em que uma data está. Agora se a partir daqui consigo chegar ao que pretendo não sei, vou experimentar.

Comment: @CesarMiguel, você pode tratar o retorno da função GetWeekInMonth() que é um inteiro entre 1 e 5 e converter para uma string (primeiro, segundo, terceiro...) facilmente com um `switch`. Com isso + as informações que você já tem você consegue montar a saída do jeito que deseja.

Comment: Mas a questão não é tratar o retorno da função. A questão é que não sei qual a data que a função está a receber por parâmetro. Eu não quero saber qual a semana de uma data, eu quero saber a data gerada para uma segunda-feira na terceira semana, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente esse método:

```
public static IList<DateTime> obterSemanaDeCadaMes(int ano, int semanaDoMes, DayOfWeek dia)
{
    int semana_atual = 1, mes_atual = 1;
    DateTime date = new DateTime(ano, 1, 1);
    IList<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

    while (date.Year == ano)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == dia && semana_atual == semanaDoMes)
            dates.Add(date);

        // Incrementa semana do mês
        if (date.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            semana_atual++;

        // Se mudar o mês reseta a semana
        if (mes_atual != date.Month)
        {
            mes_atual++;
            semana_atual = 1;
        }

        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dates = obterSemanaDeCadaMes(2014, 3, DayOfWeek.Monday);

    foreach (var data in dates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabei por arranjar uma solução. Testei a sua e também funciona! Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Obrigado pelo voto, poderia mostrar qual a solução que você optou?

Comment: Acabei agora de postar

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de construir o método que você quer para gerar datas, dada a **semana do mês** e o **dia da semana**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gera uma data, dados ano, mês, semana do mês e dia da semana.
/// A semana do mês é um número de 1 até 6.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ano">Ano da data a ser construída.</param>
/// <param name="mes">Mês da data a ser construída. Número de 1 até 12.</param>
/// <param name="semana">Semana do mês da data a ser construída. Número de 1 até 6. Note que o número máximo depende do mês. O Mês com menos semanas, terá no mínimo 4 semanas (exemplo 2015/fev).</param>
/// <param name="diaDaSemana">Dia da semana da data a ser construída.</param>
public static DateTime GerarData(int ano, int mes, int semana, DayOfWeek diaDaSemana)
{
    const long ticksNoDia = 10000000L * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var dataPrimeiroDia = new DateTime(ano, mes, 1);
    var diffDias = (semana - 1) * 7 - (int)dataPrimeiroDia.DayOfWeek + (int)diaDaSemana;
    var data = new DateTime(dataPrimeiroDia.Ticks + ticksNoDia * diffDias);

    if (data.Month != mes)
        throw new Exception("Não existe tal data!");

    return data;
}
```

Note que o método lança exceção quando não é possível construir a data... pois algumas datas são impossíveis, tal como **Domingo, da primeira semana, de fevereiro de 2014**... não existe, pois essa semana possui apenas um sábado neste mês, e nada mais.

Answer (score 0):

Segue código não testado que faz o que você precisa:

```
    static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, DateTime>> searchBaseCache;
    static DateTime GetDateGiven(int year, int month, int weekNum, int dayOfWeek)
    {
        Dictionary<string, DateTime> searchBase;
        if (!searchBaseCache.ContainsKey(year))
        {
            searchBaseCache.Add(year,BuildSearchBase(year));
        }
        searchBase = searchBaseCache[year];
        return searchBase[string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", year, month, weekNum, dayOfWeek)];
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, DateTime> BuildSearchBase(int year)
    {
        Dictionary<String, DateTime> compDates = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>(365);
        DateTime d = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        while (d.Year == year)
        {
            compDates.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", year, d.Month, GetWeekInMonth(d), d.DayOfWeek), d);
        }
        return compDates;
    }
```

Falta apenas a parte de inicialização da variavel searchBaseCache que você deve fazer no local apropriado da sua aplicação.

A função GetDateGiven irá retornar um objeto DateTime dados o ano, mês, número da semana e dia da semana.

Comment: Estou a gerar 5 listas, uma para cada semana do mês usando o seu outro exemplo. Depois testo esta resposta. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por achar uma solução, talvez não a mais eficaz. Construí a partir da resposta do @RaulAlmeira.

```
var listaDatas = new List<DateTime>(); //Lista que vai receber as datas
```

1º- Criei uma lista para cada semana do mês

```
listaDatasPrimeiraSemana = new List<DateTime>();
listaDatasSegundaSemana = new List<DateTime>();
listaDatasTerceiraSemana = new List<DateTime>();
listaDatasQuartaSemana = new List<DateTime>();
listaDatasQuintaSemana = new List<DateTime>();
```

2º- Inicializei uma data a começar no dia 1 do mês de janeiro

```
DateTime date = DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
```

3º- Preenchi as listas das semanas, correndo as cinco semanas para assim preencher todos os dias nas respectivas listas

```
while (numSemana <= 5) //Enquanto a semana for menor de 5 continua a percorrer
{
    DateTime tempdate = data.AddDays(-data.Day + 1);
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    int weekNumStart = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(tempdate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, ciCurr.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(data, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, ciCurr.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    numSemana = weekNum - weekNumStart + 1;
    if (data.AddDays(1).Month != data.Month) { break; }
    if (numSemana == 1)
    {
        listaDatasPrimeiraSemana.Add(data);
    }
    if (numSemana == 2)
    {
        listaDatasSegundaSemana.Add(data);
    }
    if (numSemana == 3)
    {
        listaDatasTerceiraSemana.Add(data);
    }
    if (numSemana == 4)
    {
        listaDatasQuartaSemana.Add(data);
    }
    if (numSemana == 5)
    {
        listaDatasQuintaSemana.Add(data);
    }
    data = data.AddDays(1);
}
```

4º- Fiz as condições para ver qual a semana que o utilizador escolheu

```
if (servico.SemanaMensalPeriod == "Primeira") //servico.SemanaMensalPeriod contém a semana escolhida pelo utilizador
{
    foreach (var item in listaDatasPrimeiraSemana)//Percorro a primeira semana
    {
        if (item.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) { listaDatas.Add(item); } //Verifico se na semana há alguma segunda feira, e caso exista adiciono à lista de datas
    }
}
...
Condição if igual à de cima para verificar se tenho alguma segunda-feira nas restantes semanas
...
```

**ATENÇÃO**

O código em cima apenas apresenta o resultado para o mês de Janeiro, para fazer para um periodo de tempo ou para o ano inteiro basta colocar o código em cima de um ciclo for e ir iterando o mês (foi como fiz, mas não achei necessário postar).

**Sei que é de longe a solução mais eficaz e tenho noção disso, apenas deixo aqui como acabei por resolver o problema. Se bem que já vi aqui soluções melhores que a minha**

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi assim:

```
private int GetWeekInMonth(DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                var weekNum = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

                return weekNum;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```